# SPARK 1.5.1: Convert multi-labeled data into binary vector

Tags: classification, apache-spark, multilabel-classification

I am using SPARK 1.5.1, and I have DataFrame that looks like follow:

```
labelsCol, featureCol
(Label1, Label2, Label 32), FeatureVector
(Label1, Label10, Label16, Label30, Label48), FeatureVector
...
(Label1, label 95), FeatureVector
```

The first column is the list of labels for that sample, and in total I have 100 label.

I would like to build a binary classifier for each label, so I want to transform the labels list column into a binary vector.

The binary vector will have a length of 100 and the value will be 0 or 1 depends on the existence of the label for sample.

Is there any strait forward solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spark only recently implemented [CountVectorizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/CountVectorizer.html), which will take the labels (as strings) and encode them as your 100-dimensional vector (assuming all 100 labels show up somewhere in your dataset).  Once you have those vectors, it should be a simple step to threshold them to make them 0/1 instead of a frequency.